# How can I combine 2 modules in STM32?

Tags: stm32, lora

As a newbie, I have a project involving an STM32 Blue Pill microcontroller. The project's objective is to read data from a DHT11 sensor and transmit it via a LoRa module.

Individually, I have successfully tested both modules. I can read data from the DHT11 and send and receive dummy data between two LoRa modules. However, when I attempt to combine these two modules in my project, I encounter issues. Specifically, I can't read data from the DHT11 anymore, and the LoRa module fails to transmit.

I'm using Timer1 to create micro-delays for the DHT11 sensor, and I'm using SPI1 for the LoRa module. Could this be causing a conflict between the two modules?

I attached the pinout:
[image: PinOut]

I can explain briefly my problem:
If I use code only for DHT11, it can read data from the DHT11 perfectly. But when I try to combine with LoRa (RF Lora SX1278 433Mhz Ra-02), it gets stuck at `while ((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (DHT11_PORT, DHT11_PIN)));`
[image: 2]
It never goes to low, and I don't know why :((

Here is my GitHub project : [My Project](https://github.com/DatChauThanh/STM32_Project) I use the STM32CubeIDE Platform.

Comment: You should probably start from one of your working projects (e.g. the one that reads the DHT11 sensor), then slowly start integrating the LoRa stuff into that, while making sure you haven't broken the sensor reading at each stage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SPI1 is on PA5/6/7. And a LoRa module (which one are you using?) requires a few more GPIOs. So check that the pins you are using for the LoRa module don't conflict with the DHT11 and Timer1. I have STM32 projects with LoRa, I2C, and more, that work flawlessly.

Maybe show some code and a pinout.

Comment: I added more detail u said .Hope to hear u respond soon :)